# Сортировка DISTINCT CASE

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надо получить уникальных id пользователей, которые отправляли сообщения пользователю "1".

Составил запрос

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CASE
                WHEN user_add='1'
                   THEN user_from
                WHEN user_from='1'
                   THEN user_add
                END
             ) AS user_id FROM message WHERE user_add='1' OR user_from = '1'
```

результат

[image]

Вопрос как отсортировать по дате или id,  ORDER BY id DESC не работает?

---

Все, вот так работает:

`SELECT CASE
        WHEN user_add='1'
          THEN user_from
        WHEN user_from='1'
          THEN user_add
        END 
          AS user_id , max(id)
FROM message
WHERE user_add='1' OR user_from = '1' group by user_id order by max(id) DESC`

Спасибо!

Comment: убрать distinct, добавить `group by 1` (т.е. вот по тому case) и сортировать по max(date_add)

Comment: Не понял тебя, максимум что получилось

SELECT CASE
        WHEN user_add='1'
          THEN user_from
        WHEN user_from='1'
          THEN user_add
        END 
          AS user_id , max(id)
FROM message
WHERE user_add='1' OR user_from = '1' group by user_id

но и то сортировка не верна, напиши пожалуйста как ты имел ввиду, уже стул горит

Comment: к своему запросу добавьте требуемый order by, например `order by max(id) desc`. А что бы получить более полный ответ отредактируйте вопрос и укажите в каком порядке должны оказаться записи, на тех данных, которые показаны в вопросе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT user_add id
    FROM message 
    WHERE user_from = 1
UNION
    SELECT user_from
    FROM message 
    WHERE user_add = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cb27a6612eddb3c6701a9ce4d13ef5aa)

Comment: Нет не работает

Comment: Значит, у Вас косяк. Добавил fiddle.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c3c4521eb26c8782fc6cf409d0505b24

вот добавил (6,1) ответ должен быть 6,2,3,5

Comment: @DenKapone А, может, 6,5,3,2? Или мы по-разному понимаем сортировку по убыванию?

Comment: Не, именно 6,2,3,5, Вы просто не поняли как надо отсортировать, задача выбрать уникальные id пользователей с кем пользователь 1 вел беседу и отсортировать их по времени или id последних сообщений которые появлялись в результате диалога. Тесть первый в списке тот пользователь с которым пользователь 1 обменивался позже всех и т.д. Моя вина, я не совсем корректно описал задачу.